# insert click_url, timestamp and username when user clicks a link

Tags: php, mysql, logging, hyperlink, insert

i was going to have a menu consisting of images which differed depending on if a new record was added since the users last visit.

However I decided to move away from that idea and I am now going for comparing last timestamp on clicked link with timestamp on new record.

I tried to find a solution but I am stuck at this line right now, maybe you can see what's wrong with it (clicks is my table where I want to store the clicks):

```
$sql = "insert into clicks (username, link_url, click_timestamp) values ($_SESSION[$username], "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]", now())";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

So, anybody have any good ideas? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your SQL syntax, try this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO clicks (username, link_url, click_timestamp) VALUES
        ("' . $_SESSION[$username] . '",  
         "http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '", 
          NOW()
        )';
```

Comment: Thank you, it works except that the username isn't logged, do you have any idea why?

Comment: ok, now it works! this is how it looks now: $username = $_SESSION['username']; $sql = 'INSERT INTO clicks (username, link_url, click_timestamp) VALUES
        ("'. $username .'",  
         "http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '", 
          NOW()
        )';
$result=mysql_query($sql);

Answer (score 0):

Check that string. As ar as I know, PHP can solve plain variables inside a string, but cannot solve an array, so `$_SESSION` in this case should go outside the string. Also, if you want to put quotes inside a string, use a backslash before it, like `\"`, so it's gonna be interpreted as a quote character instead of an end of string.